# React componentDidMount() is fired on unMounted component

Tags: reactjs, setstate

A simple react component that invokes a promise from the data store on `componentDidMount` is throwing a warning:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the LocationNameView component.

I threw a few debug `console.log` to see if `this.isMounted()` is true/false, and inside `componentDidMount` `this.isMounted()` will return false the first time then again and it will be true. I'm not sure if the docs are clear or the name of `componentDidMount` is skewing my reasoning here but it seems like this method should only be invoked if the component is actually mounted.

[enter link description here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount)

```
componentDidMount: function() {

  var self = this;
  // make the request to the backend and replace the loading location text
  Models.Location.find(this.props.location)
    .then(function(location) {

        console.log(self.isMounted()); // <--- shows false then true 

        self.setState({ location : location });

    });

},
```

Comment: I found some useful information: [link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2787)
There are explanations on using isMounted() to safeguard against asynchronous callbacks like in my example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is invoked when the underlying DOM representation is built, but, not yet mounted to the actual DOM.

The reason the warning is being displayed about setting state on an unMounted component is because the aSync callback in the above example can return before the component is actually mounted to the DOM tree in the client/browser.

The lesson here is if you're using an aSync callback that sets state in your component on `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`, first use the safety catch `isMounted()` before proceeding to setting state, ie:

```
componentDidMount() {

  let self = this;

  PromiseMethod().then(function aSyncCallback(data) {

    if ( self.isMounted() ) {

      self.setState({...data});

    }

  });

}
```

[React Component Lifecycle reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539884/react-componentdidmount-is-fired-on-unmounted-component/34541323#34541323)

Comment: What is the recommended recovery action in case isMounted returns false here ?
I assume there is still an interest in setting that state on a mounted component.

Comment: The component is not mounted meaning it's not in the virtual DOM so if it's false you cannot set the state.

Comment: This appears to be deprecated.  Is there another way to check if we are mounted?  Not seeing anything useful on the Component class in typescript definition...

Does it also seem very odd that this lifecycle hook would fire before the DOM is actually mounted?

Comment: How did you run `self.isMounted()`? For me I get many errors by doing so